# I am trying to get markers near user location by calculating distance using haversine formula

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, warnings, marker

Hey guys can anybody help me why i am getting an error in this code

Here is the code.

```
getWithinDistance: function(){
    var selectedMarker = [];
    var lat1 = this.state.region.latitude;
    var lon1 = this.state.region.longitude;
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++)
      {
      var lat2 = this.state.a[i].latitude;
      var lon2 = this.state.a[i].longitude;
      var R = 6371;
      var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * (Math.PI/180);
      var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * (Math.PI/180);
      var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos((lat1) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos((lat2) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
      var d = R * c;
      if(d <= 2.00){
        var latlng = {
          latitude: lat2,
          longitude: lon2
        }
        selectedMarker.push(latlng);
      }
      }
      console.log(selectedMarker);
      var at = selectedMarker.map(marker => {
        return(
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={marker.latlng} />
        );
      })
},
```

I am getting Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `coordinate` was not specified. but when i log it i can see two markers in the array selectedMarker[]

here is the snap of log which i get 
[image: getting a warning]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the return statement inside your for loop. So the the loop will exit after the first iteration.

Take these lines out of the for loop.

```
return (
      <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.a[i]} />
    );
```

Edit your for loop to store all the markers that are within the required distance in an array and then after the for loop return that array

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map() to iterate and get the values.

Like this:

### (ES6 Style)

```
getWithinDistance: function(){

    const lat1 = this.state.region.latitude;
    const lon1 = this.state.region.longitude;
    const R = 6371 

    this.state.a.map(coordinate => {
    const dLat = (coordinate.latitude - lat1) * (Math.PI/180)
    const dLon = (coordinate.longitude - lon1) * (Math.PI/180)
    const a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos((lat1) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos((lat2) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  const d = R * c
        console.log(coordinate, d)
    }       
}
```

This will show the coordinates with their distance to your location.

The return statement has to be outside the map() function. And return whatever you want to achieve.